# How can I query an EF6 collection property within a LINQ Where clause?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am attempting to use the following query to extract a group model from a database:

```
var group = await _context.Groups
    .Where(g => g.ID == dto.GroupID && g.Users.Contains(user))
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

`dto` is a request DTO sent via a Web API, and `user` is an ASP.NET IdentityUser.

This throws an exception as Entity Framework cannot convert user into a constant. Is there any way to achieve this query?

I have an alternative in the following code:

```
var reportingGroup = user.Groups
    .FirstOrDefault(rg => dto.GroupID == rg.ID);
```

But I'd like to avoid the synchronous lookup on the user's lazy-loaded Groups collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More correct would to be to match users by `Id` not by whole `User` object. So consider to change

```
g.Users.Contains(user)
```

To

```
g.Users.Any(u=>u.Id==user.Id)
```

Comment: or g.Users.Select(u=>u.Id).Contains(user.Id)

Comment: I think option - `g.Users.Any(u=>u.Id==user.Id)` would be more correct.